# How does SLSQP uses the termination criterion parameter ftol in scipy.optimizer.minimize?

Tags: scipy-optimize-minimize, quadratic-programming

I would like to know how the SLSQP optimizer in scipy.optimizer.minimize uses the 'ftol' parameter for a problem with equality and inequality constraints?
I would like to know exactly how the termination criterion is applied.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A copy of the original paper can be found here:

https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2022/02/slsqp-original-paper.html

Comment: The link is dead. Do you have the title or author of the paper, or a summary of the relevant details?

Comment: @SamJaques See [link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2022/02/slsqp-original-paper.html).